# How to only allow a file to be opened or executed by certain application(s)?

Tags: permissions, files, security, execute-command

Let's say that I've got a security application (or something which I just don't want any old application or user to have access to because it is very important and if the wrong guys had access to it might be quite a problem) which is owned and can only be run by root. However I have installed another application which is also owned by root and thus can only be run by root as root.

However I do not wish for this other application to be able to execute any files to do with my security application, nor do I want it to be able to read or write to any of those files, so is there any way for me to specify which applications are allowed to execute, read, and write to the specified files of that security application?

This is a hypothetical situation, but it does exist sort of in reality as it is a bit of a security risk, so can I make it so that a file/application can only be executed by certain applications? As well as only giving read and write permissions to certain applications? Though remember, all these applications are run as root, so I'm not sure if different user groups would be an option.

And it's not only an issue with these applications, for instance I have some files owned by normal users which I only want certain applications to have access to though those applications are all run by the same user.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Gui applications or cli?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Both.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Never got anywhere with this then? :)